# Mostrar descripción de una lista de arrays en angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript

tengo un array que con tiene nombre, id, descripción. En el html solo muestro los id con un boton, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando le de click a un botón me muestre la información de ese id (nombre y descripción)

```
datos = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice', description:"aaaa" },
    { id: 12, name: 'Narco', description:"aaaa" },
    { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto', description:"aaaa" },
    { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas', description:"aaaa" },
    { id: 15, name: 'Magneta', description:"aaaa" },
    { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' , description:"aaaa"},
    { id: 17, name: 'Dynama', description:"aaaa" },
    { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ', description:"aaaa" },
    { id: 19, name: 'Magma', description:"aaaa" },
    { id: 20, name: 'Tornado', description:"aaaa" }
  ];
informacion(){
}
```

HTML

```
<div  *ngFor="let datos of datos">
{{datos.id}}
<button  (click)="informacion()">Ver informacion</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podés hacer algo como esto:

```
datos = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice', description:"aaaa" },
    { id: 12, name: 'Narco', description:"aaaa" },
    { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto', description:"aaaa" },
    { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas', description:"aaaa" },
    { id: 15, name: 'Magneta', description:"aaaa" },
    { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' , description:"aaaa"},
    { id: 17, name: 'Dynama', description:"aaaa" },
    { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ', description:"aaaa" },
    { id: 19, name: 'Magma', description:"aaaa" },
    { id: 20, name: 'Tornado', description:"aaaa" }
  ];

public datoSeleccionado = null;
public informacion(dato){
   this.datoSeleccionado = dato;
}
```

Y en el HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let dato of datos">
    <button (click)="informacion(dato)">Ver informacion de {{dato.id}} </button>
 </div>
 <ng-container *ngIf="datoSeleccionado">
     Nombre - {{ datoSeleccionado.name }}
     Descripción - {{ datoSeleccionado.description }}
 </ng-container>
```

Comment: Hola Bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Te invito realizar un [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozca cómo funciona el sitio 
y ganes tu primera medalla. Además, puedes leer [answer]. Si bien tú respuesta puede ser la solución que necesita la pregunta, es mucho mejor para él y para otros, que la acompañes de una breve explicación del porqué soluciona el problema. Ganando la misma en calidad.